# Keeping variable value after closing the application

Tags: android

In my app I have a ListView where each row is an element with several attributes like name, icon and favorite.

A class:

```
public class ItemFileGroup implements Parcelable{
  protected String name;
  protected String icon;
  protected boolean favorite;
...}
```

Main class:

```
ArrayList<ItemFileGroup> items = new ArrayList<ItemFileGroup>();
```

I need the favorite attribute hold true or false even after you close the application and reopen it. Therefore, at start, favorite values false but if user clicks it favorite values true, and when app is closed and started again favorite must values true.

What is the best way to maintain the value attribute favorite after app is closed?

Thank You

Comment: Have you read the [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) documentation?

Comment: What option you recommend me?

Comment: Based on the very limited knowledge I have of your project, a SQLite database is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I think that for saving small things such as numbers, strings etc you should use the SharedPreferences class. Take a look at this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).